# P5.js Creating a fading curve on a grid

Tags: p5.js, curve

I've made a square grid on top of the canvas and also a cruve (that is meant to have a fading trail). I made them seperately and tried combining them so the curve would appear on top of the grid. However, it doesn't show the curve.
I've commented out the grid so it's easier to see the curve.
How do I get this to work?

```
var cols = 10;
var rows = 10;
var t = 0;
var particleArray = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(0);
  fill(100);
  rect(0, 0, 550, 550, 25);

}


// blue grid
function draw() {
  /*for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var XO = 25 + c * 50;
        var YO = 25 + r * 50;
        stroke(0);
        fill(100,149,237);
        rect(XO, YO, 50, 50);
        noLoop();
        // :(
    }
  }
*/
    //curve

    y = width / 2 +  270 * sin(3 * t + PI / 2) - 25;
    x = height / 2 + 270 * sin(1 * t) - 25;
  
    particleArray.push(new Particle(x, y, t));
    for (i=0; i<particleArray.length; i++) {
    particleArray[i].show(t);
  }
  if (particleArray.length > 700) {
    particleArray.shift();
 }
 t += .01;
}

function Particle(x, y, t) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.t = t;
  
  this.show = function(currentT) {
    var _ratio = t / currentT;
    _alpha = map(_ratio, 0, 1, 0, 255); //points will fade out as time elaps
    fill(255, 255, 255, _alpha);
    ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: No one here is going to trust a google drive link: if you have p5 code, consider putting up a link to a https://editor.p5js.org/ sketch, and include your (reduced) cost in your post (e.g. if you have code in a huge block comment, remove that. If it's not part of the problem that the question is for, don't include it)

Comment: Oh alright, it was just an example gif

Comment: then why text-link to it? There's an image linker right in the edit bar when you're writing/editing your post =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this was intentional but you called `noLoop()` function where you're drawing the grid. If you comment that out it works.